# JS Object comes out as undefined

Tags: javascript, html

When I write onto the document the object comes out as undefined and I don't know why. Any help you be greatly appreciated. P.S I'm relatively new to JS so I am still learning.

```js
function car(make, model, year, color, passengers, convertible, mileage) {
  this.make = make;
  this.model = model;
  this.year = year;
  this.color = color;
  this.passengers = passengers;
  this.convertible = convertible;
  this.mileage = mileage;
}

var carParams = {
  make: "Toyota",
  model: "Prius",
  year: 2012,
  color: "red",
  passengers: 1,
  convertible: false,
  mileage: 3403,
};
var toyota = new car(carParams);
document.write(
  "The " +
  toyota.make +
  " " +
  toyota.model +
  " is a really fast car because it is " +
  toyota.color +
  "."
);
```

Comment: Your `car` function expects 7 parameters but you are only passing 1. Perhaps you meant to destructure the argument... `function car({ make, model, year, color, passengers, convertible, mileage }) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing one argument (an object) into the `car` constructor, but the `car` constructor expects you to pass multiple arguments, one for each of the attribute of the car. So the one argument you are passing is saved as the `make` (that's why you see `"[object Object]"`), and everything else is the value `undefined`.

Either pass discrete arguments (no object, just a long arguments list), like this:

```js
function car(make, model, year, color, passengers, convertible, mileage) {
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.color = color;
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.convertible = convertible;
    this.mileage = mileage;
}

var toyota = new car(
    "Toyota",
    "Prius",
    2012,
    "red",
    1,
    false,
    3403,
);
document.write(
      "The " +
      toyota.make +
      " " +
      toyota.model +
      " is a really fast car because it is " +
      toyota.color +
      "."
);
```

But passing in that many discrete arguments, it's easy to get the order wrong, or to forget which one is which (although modern IDEs make that a lot easier), so passing in an object asyou did can be clearer since you specify the property names explicitly. When you want to do that, you need to accept a single parameter (the entire object) and use that. In modern code, you'd probably do that with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), which leads to a very small change to your code:

```js
function car({make, model, year, color, passengers, convertible, mileage}) {
    //       ^                                                          ^
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.color = color;
    this.passengers = passengers;
    this.convertible = convertible;
    this.mileage = mileage;
}

var carParams = {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Prius",
    year: 2012,
    color: "red",
    passengers: 1,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 3403,
};
var toyota = new car(carParams);
document.write(
      "The " +
      toyota.make +
      " " +
      toyota.model +
      " is a really fast car because it is " +
      toyota.color +
      "."
);
```

For clarity, that does effectively the same thing this does:

```js
function car(params) {
    this.make = params.make;
    this.model = params.model;
    this.year = params.year;
    this.color = params.color;
    this.passengers = params.passengers;
    this.convertible = params.convertible;
    this.mileage = params.mileage;
}

var carParams = {
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Prius",
    year: 2012,
    color: "red",
    passengers: 1,
    convertible: false,
    mileage: 3403,
};
var toyota = new car(carParams);
document.write(
      "The " +
      toyota.make +
      " " +
      toyota.model +
      " is a really fast car because it is " +
      toyota.color +
      "."
);
```

---

A couple of side notes:

1. While it may be okay in very simple tests like this one, in general, avoid `document.write`. Instead, use [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) methods to create an add elements to the page.
2. The overwhelmingly-common convention in JavaScript code is that constructor functions like your `car` start with a capital letter (`Car`). You don't have to follow that convention, but I recommend you do, it'll make your code much clearer to other people reading it.
3. The `var` keyword is effectively deprecated. Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) or [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing all the properties in a single object,So in the function `make` is the parameter which is accepting `carParams` while rest are undefined

```js
function car(carParams) {
  this.make = carParams.make;
  this.model = carParams.model;
  this.year = carParams.year;
  this.color = carParams.color;
  this.passengers = carParams.passengers;
  this.convertible = carParams.convertible;
  this.mileage = carParams.mileage;
}

var carParams = {
  make: "Toyota",
  model: "Prius",
  year: 2012,
  color: "red",
  passengers: 1,
  convertible: false,
  mileage: 3403,
};
var toyota = new car(carParams);
document.write(
  "The " +
  toyota.make +
  " " +
  toyota.model +
  " is a really fast car because it is " +
  toyota.color +
  "."
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```
var toyota = new car(carParams.make, carParams.model, carParams.year, carParams.color, carParams.passengers, carParams.convertible, carParams.mileage);
```